# How to format manipulated DateTime fields in dynamic TSQL

Tags: t-sql, date, datetime, dynamic, time

I have a query that looks basically like this, wrapped in a dynamic query to accommodate table names that can change.  I got the date functions in the middle converted but it doesn't like the LoadedDateTime and CallPlacedTime at the end.  I've tried every conversion and combination of quoting those lines that I can think of.  How can I accomplish this?

```
DECLARE @sql_TotalDialsNewLeads nvarchar(1000) = N'
 SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ' + @tbl_CH + ' ch, ' + @tbl_CL + ' cl, ' + @tbl_DA + ' da
  WHERE ch.IDENTITY = cl.IDENTITY
    AND cl.CRMID = da.CRMID
    AND CallPlacedTime BETWEEN ''' +  CONVERT(varchar(30),DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,@StartDate),126) + '''
                           AND ''' +  CONVERT(varchar(30),DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,@EndDate),126) + '''
    AND Product = ''' + @Product + '''
    AND Country = ''' + @Country + '''
    AND DATEPART(DayOfYear,DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,LoadedDateTime))
      = DATEPART(DayOfYear,DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,CallPlacedTime))'

 EXECUTE(@sql_TotalDialsNewLeads);
```

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sp_executesql` with parameters instead of making string to execute manually:

```
...    
AND CallPlacedTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,@StartDate) 
AND DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,@EndDate)
...
```

and execute it with the following statement:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql_TotalDialsNewLeads, 
N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime',
@StartDate,@EndDate;
```

Here is a [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). Also you can do it for other parameters in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the conversion outside use it inside the dynamic query.

something like this. (Not tested)

```
DECLARE @sql_TotalDialsNewLeads nvarchar(1000) = N'
 SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ' + @tbl_CH + ' ch, ' + @tbl_CL + ' cl, ' + @tbl_DA + ' da
  WHERE ch.IDENTITY = cl.IDENTITY
    AND cl.CRMID = da.CRMID
    AND CallPlacedTime BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(30),DATEADD(HOUR,'''+ -@TimezoneOffset +''','''+ @StartDate +'''),126)
                           AND CONVERT(varchar(30),DATEADD(HOUR,'''+ -@TimezoneOffset +''','''+ @EndDate +'''),126)
    AND Product = ''' + @Product + '''
    AND Country = ''' + @Country + '''
    AND DATEPART(DayOfYear,DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,LoadedDateTime))
      = DATEPART(DayOfYear,DATEADD(HOUR,-@TimezoneOffset,CallPlacedTime))'

 EXECUTE(@sql_TotalDialsNewLeads);
```